# How do you develop an app on Ubuntu with a simple GUI?

Tags: 20.04, application-development, gui

How do you develop an app on Ubuntu with a simple GUI?
I have looked everywhere and I can't find a way.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what it is you want to do?

Comment: You generally develop using whatever toolkit you find most convenient for you to use. Ubuntu has support for nearly all of them.

Answer (score 4):

Earlier this year Canonical started to move towards [making Flutter one of the “first class” development tools](https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-flutter-on-ubuntu) for Ubuntu. If you are experienced with a bit of the web development toolkit (HTML/CSS/JavaScript), then you can quickly adapt to use Flutter to create applications that will run on Ubuntu. There are a number of IDEs that support the language, such as Sublime Text and Microsoft Code, as well as a wealth of online tutorials. Flutter is cross-platform, so can be used to make applications for the major operating systems. As a result, there are a lot of resources online to learn from … though few are Linux-specific.

Check out the example in the link above, or take a look at [the main Flutter page](https://flutter.dev/), which has far more examples, links to training resources, plus some pretty comprehensive documentation

Comment: Maybe you should mention that the actual programming language used in Flutter is [Dart](https://dart.dev/).

Comment: @ArturMeinild You can [suggest an edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1377917/edit) to add that if  you want